# Quartz Cron syntax: every 10 mins between 8am and 4:30

Tags: cron, quartz-scheduler

I'm trying to write a Quartz task that runs on a cron schedule of every 10 minutes between 8am and 4:30pm.

If It was just between 8am and 4pm I would use

```
s   m  h   dom M dow
0 */10 8-16 ?   * MON-FRI
```

But I need it to run until 4:30 not just 4...
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case you are probably better off using a [DailyTimeIntervalTrigger](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.0/org/quartz/DailyTimeIntervalTrigger.html) rather than a CronTrigger. Here is a screenshot from [QuartzDesk](https://www.quartzdesk.com) (our Quartz management and monitoring GUI) that shows you an example of a DailyTimeIntervalTrigger with attributes that meet your scheduling requirements:

[image: Example of Daily Time Interval trigger]

Answer (score 2):

I think it is impossible to express such requirement in one cron schedule . I would create two cron schedules instead :

1. `0 */10 8-15 ?   * MON-FRI`  (Run from 8:00am to 3:50pm every 10 minutes)
2. `0 0,10,20,30 16 ? * MON-FRI` (Run at 4:00pm , 4:10pm , 4:20pm , 4:30pm)