# In databricks I want to schedule a job from 12 AM to 11.30 PM for every 1 minute

Tags: azure, cron, databricks, scheduling

Can we implement this scenario in a single job instead of 2 different jobs

0 0/1 00-22 * * ?
The above cron syntax is running a job from 12 AM to 10:59 PM for every 1 minute. Please let me know is there any way we can run upto 11.30 PM in a single job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible with a single Databricks job, although the limitation is with Cron expressions, not Databricks.

See the following Question for example: [Quartz Cron syntax: every 10 mins between 8am and 4:30](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34137719/quartz-cron-syntax-every-10-mins-between-8am-and-430)